# How to swap minus sign from last position in a string to first position in hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

How to swap negative sign from last position to first in a string  or integer to first position in hive and/ spark?

example:  22-

required:  -22

My code is:

```
val Validation1 = spark.sql("Select case when substr(YTTLSVAL-,-1,1)='-' then cast(concat('-',substr(YTTLSVAL-,1,length(YTTLSVAL-)-1)) as int) else cast(YTTLSVAL- as int) end as column_name")
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you provide any examples?

Comment: @naveed navaz, Any problem on the result you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scala> Seq("-abcd", "def", "23-", "we").toDF("value").createOrReplaceTempView("values")
scala> val f = (x: String) => if(x.endsWith("-")) s"-${x.dropRight(1)}" else x
scala> spark.udf.register("myudf", f)
scala> spark.sql("select *, myudf(*) as custval from values").show
+-----+-------+
|value|custval|
+-----+-------+
|-abcd|  -abcd|
|  def|    def|
|  23-|    -23|
|   we|     we|
+-----+-------+
```

#### EDIT

On second thought, since, UDF's are discouraged unless you absolutely need them (since they create a black box for spark's optimisation engine), please use below way that uses `regex_replace` instead. Have tested this and it works:

```
scala> spark.sql("select REGEXP_REPLACE ( value, '^(\\.+)(-)$','-$1') as custval from values").show
```

Comment: @NaveedNavaz, please consider marking as answer, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `REGEXP_REPLACE`. This patter searches for a number followed by `-` at the end and puts it before the number if found.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ( val, '^(\\d+)-$','-$1')
```

[**Column functions**](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/2556313/Column+Functions+and+Properties+Spark+SQL)